# Elasticsearch on OSX -- Java

Tags: java, macos, elasticsearch

I have multiple Java versions on my OSX Sierra (including Java8).

I have to maintain /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java to "1.6.0_65" because of legacy application which I need :(

All fine and dandy....but Java8 is required for Elasticsearch -- is there a way I can point Elasticsearch to Java8 JRE -- but leave System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java as  1.6.0_65?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that Elasticsearch requires is for `JAVA_HOME` to reference the desired version of Java. You can have as many versions of Java on your machine as you would like as long as `JAVA_HOME` references Java 8.